# I may be a fraud

Tags: riddle, wordplay

I may be a fraud.

But give me your admiration and I shall dominate late night TV.

Give me a stone and I shall be a symbol of celebration.

Give me your filth and I shall make you clean.

Give me but one letter and I am a killer.

Give me most of your approval and I shall leave you in ruins.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

I may be a fraud.

> sham

But give me your admiration and I shall dominate late night TV.

> ShamWow (credit to [TwoBitOperation](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/users/29430/twobitoperation))

Give me a stone and I shall be a symbol of celebration.

> shamrock

Give me your filth and I shall make you clean.

> shampoo

Give me but one letter and I am a killer.

> Shamu

Give me most of your approval and I shall leave you in ruins.

> shambles (bless)

Comment: Second one is most likely ROT(Funz-jbj)

Comment: Well that was fast - Correct on all but the "killer" clue - though that is what I feel because I should've made a clue that had that answer...

Comment: Okay, after the 2nd edit, this is now correct.  That first one...  disturbing...  And apparently deleted from history - I guess if you edit it fast enough it erases it...